# Numpy has mysteriously stopped working

Tags: python, numpy

I was trying to get this [ConvexHull](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html) function running, and I needed numpy (I think) to get it to work.  I'm going to try to get numpy uninstalled and reinstalled, but I'm not sure why/how this happened so that I can prevent it from happening again.

While I was running through some of the examples, I decided to stop running from the prompt to save some typing.  When I ran the seemingly same bits of code from a file, it returned the following error message:

```
>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2218, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/numpy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from numpy import show_config as show_numpy_config
  File "C:/Python34\numpy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\__init__.py", line 90, in <module>
    from .kdtree import *
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\kdtree.py", line 8, in <module>
    import scipy.sparse
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\__init__.py", line 212, in <module>
    from .base import *
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scipy._lib.six import xrange
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from numpy.testing import Tester
ImportError: No module named 'numpy.testing'; 'numpy' is not a package
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
```

Now, when I type `import numpy` from the prompt, it returns:

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#40>", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:/Python34\numpy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from numpy import show_config as show_numpy_config
ImportError: cannot import name 'show_config'
```

The entire setup was running without issue a few minutes ago, and I am unsure exactly why this all stopped.

The full text of my commands is [here](http://dumptext.com/tmbjexKy#).  The file was short, `C:\Python34\numpy.py` with the following contents:

```
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
import numpy as np
points = np.random.rand(30,2)
```

Comment: Change the file name to something different than `numpy.py`.

Comment: @Sait Wow, I can't believe how unbelievably stupid I am...  Thank you so much.  Everything is back to normal.

Comment: This is not stupidity. I spent hundreds of hours to debug this kind of mistakes. :-)

Comment: Also, you should probably stop doing your work in the Python install directory.

Comment: @user2357112 Typically, I don't; in this case, however, I was just trying to see results fast and didn't check the default file path as I should have.

Comment: @Sait, should you post an answer so that this question leaves the "Unanswered" section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the file name to something different than `numpy.py`.